# For Container Transaction the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, ejb-2.x, jboss-4.2.x

I am getting the error of "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed" for container transaction.

The ejb-jar.xml code is given below:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
    EmployeeDetails
    
    
    EmployeeDetails
    EmployeeBean
    com.test.intrfc.EmployeeHome
    com.test.intrfc.EmployeeRemote
    com.test.classes.EmployeeBean
    Container
    com.test.classes.EmployeePK
    false
    2.x
    EmployeeRemote
    
    employeeid
    
    
    employeeName
    
    
    shareAmount
    
    
    shareValue
    
    employeeid
    
    Finds a Employee bean by the name of an employee
    
    findByEmployeeName
    
    java.lang.String
    
    
    Select Object(a) FROM EmployeeRemote
    As a Where a.employeeName=?1

```
<container-transaction>
    <method>
        <ejb-name>EmployeeBean</ejb-name>
        <method-intf>EmployeeHome</method-intf>
        <method-name>remove</method-name>
        <method-params>
        <method-param>java.lang.Object</method-param>
        </method-params>
    </method>
        <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

This quote from `ejb-jar_2_1.xsd` should give you the answer:

> The method-intf element allows a method element to
>       differentiate between the methods with the same name and
>       signature that are multiply defined across the home and
>       component interfaces (e.g, in both an enterprise bean's
>       remote and local interfaces or in both an enterprise bean's
>       home and remote interfaces, etc.); the component and web
>       service endpoint interfaces, and so on.

```
The method-intf element must be one of the following:

    Home
    Remote
    LocalHome
    Local
    ServiceEndpoint
```